# unix2dos equivalent in linux

Tags: linux, unix, migration

I am planning to migrate my application coded in C/C++ and running on UNIX to Linux Suse 11.1. I have some places where unix2dos is used. I knew that flip is alternative to unix2dos in linux. Please let me know is there any risk involved in using flip on linux as unix2dos equivalent?

Comment: It's `unix2dos`, you probably have to install it, but otherwise, `flip` works just as well, but is less known.

Comment: What really got me here is why you'd employ an external dependency when it seems almost trivial to [do the conversion yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761108/replace-cr-lf-with-lf-in-c) ... you'd obviously wan to do the reverse of what happens there, but still ...

Answer (score 7):

CentOS no longer includes it in a default distro, but is readily available.

Command:

```
yum install unix2dos
```

You may as well install its mirror image, dos2unix

```
yum install dos2unix
```

For some reason, saving 35k of space on a distro was that important, so we can keep updating threads like this.

:| have an edited day.

Comment: OMG - It's a year later to the day, and I am rereading my responses.

Answer (score 3):

Most Linux distributions I know of include `unix2dos` and `dos2unix`. As of Ubuntu 10.04, these utilities were dropped from the default installation, but were easily added by installing to `tofrodos` package using the following command.

`sudo aptitude install tofrodos`

To date, both Red Hat and its non-branded CentOS cousins have always contained these utilities.

Comment: Today, `sudo apt install tofrodos` didn't install `unix2dos` for me (I didn't check `dos2unix`). I'm not sure what it did, actually. Regardless, [sudo apt install dos2unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77462935/61624) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu dos2unix is in the Universe repository.
sudo apt-get install dos2unix

See also http://packages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search_packages.pl?keywords=dos2unix&searchon=names&version=all&release=all

Linux Mint: http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/dos2unix

The risk of flip is that you might convert Unix line breaks to DOS line breaks, while you expected the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Linux does have `unix2dos` and `dos2unix`.

Comment: At least [Debian does](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/tofrodos), it's probably packaged for other distros too

Comment: please let me know is it available on Linux Suse 11.1

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu in 2023:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

This installs `dos2unix` **and** `unix2dos`.