# Switch statement bash script not working

Tags: bash, jar, switch-statement

Sometimes, when I run the code, it works when its in an outside directory.
However, when I move it inside another directory, it ends up not working (I use absolute filepaths, so it shouldn't be a problem)

This is the code that I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in

"-h") 
    printf "\nHelp\n"
    printf  $"Stuff here.."
    ;;

"-c") 
    echo "The start time is $2"
    echo "The end time is $3"
    java -jar someJar.jar "$2" "$3";
    ;;
"-v")
    java -jar someJar.jar v;
    ;;
*) 
    java -jar someJar.jar;
    ;;

esac

printf "\n\n"
```

This is the error I get. The odd part is my file name is `run.sh`, and when I call it, I use `sh run.sh`, but it says `un.sh` below for the error:

```
: command not found
'un.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `in
'un.sh: line 3: `case "$1" in
```

`od -cx` command result:

```
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   s   h  \r  \n  \r  \n   c   a   s
           2123    622f    6e69    732f    0d68    0d0a    630a    7361
0000020   e       $   1       i   n  \r  \n  \r  \n   "   -   h   "   )
           2065    3124    6920    0d6e    0d0a    220a    682d    2922
0000040      \r  \n  \t   p   r   i   n   t   f       "   \   n   H   e
           0d20    090a    7270    6e69    6674    2220    6e5c    6548
0000060   l   p   \   n   "  \r  \n  \t   p   r   i   n   t   f
           706c    6e5c    0d22    090a    7270    6e69    6674    2020
0000100   $   "   T   o       r   u   n       t   h   e       p   r   o
           2224    6f54    7220    6e75    7420    6568    7020    6f72
```

Comment: Are you running it under some bash implementation on windows? I have seen some weird errors that got fixed by running `dos2unix` on the shell script

Comment: @MiserableVariable I'm running it via SSH on Linux (SSH client is on a Windows)

Comment: Did the script get copied from windows to dos? Paste the output of `od -cx run.sh |head`

Comment: Technically `bash != sh`, call it with `./run.sh` if it's executable or `bash run.sh`. Though I doubt this is the error, since `case` is posix complaint.

Comment: @MiserableVariable I added the output above

Comment: @BroSlow I tried that, and yeah, I got the same exact error

Comment: @user3ffgfgfgfgfg50064 `dos2unix` should fix the error, based on your edited output (i.e. dos `\r\n` line endings)

Comment: @BroSlow How and where exactly should I use `dos2unix`

Comment: @MiserableVariable is right - you need to run dos2unix on Linux, because your run.sh is in Dos format (0d0a is used as line ending)

Comment: This is addressed in the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on exchanges in comments and the updated question, it seems the error is caused by dos style end of line characters in the script.

DOS uses the character pair `\r\n` for marking end-of-line in text files while unix uses `\n`. There are multiple ways to fix the error, but the simplest is to run `dos2unix` on it as follows:

```
dos2unix run.sh
```

The problem is typically caused by copying files from unix to windows in ASCII mode, for example using ASCII mode `get` with `ftp`, and copying back to unix in binary mode, for example using `ssh`

Comment: For some reason, I don't have the `dos2unix` command. I checked in the `usr/bin` directory but it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Which OS are you running the script on? Does it have `d2u`?

Comment: It doesn't have it. I am running version 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 of Linux

Comment: @user3ffgfgfgfgfg50064 `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`. Or just open the file `vim run.sh`, and run `:set ff=unix`, followed by `:wq`.

Comment: The second option worked great, thanks for your help.

Comment: The right answer is not mine, even though it would have worked you had `dos2unix`. @BrowSlow should add an answer and that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I couldn't really use dos2unix. I tried using the command you mentioned but couldn't get it to run due to some permissions/policies.

Comment: Which flavor of linux are you using? Have installed packages in past? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654306/unix2dos-equivalent-in-linux) question on SO has a good explanation of how to install dos2unix.