# Replace CR LF with LF in C

Tags: c, newline, carriage-return

I have to write a C program that somewhat function like dos2unix. Which replace all `CR` `LF` with only `LF` (DOS-Format to Unix-Format). 
So this is my way of approach. Everytime I read a line, I search for the end of the data by lookng for `\0`and then check if the following are `\r\n`.
If yes replace with `\n`only. But it seems do not work and the line `CRLF here` never been printed out once.

```
char data[255]; // save the data from in.txt
char *checker;
pf = fopen("in.txt", "r");
pf2 = fopen("out.txt", "w");
while (feof(pf) == 0)
{
    fgets(data, 255, pf);       // Read input data
    checker = data;
    while (checker != "\0") // Search for a new line
    {
        if (checker == "\r\n") // Check if this is CR LF
        {
            printf("CRLF here");
            checker = "\n";   // replace with LF
        }
        checker++;
    }
    fputs(data, pf2);       // Write to output data
}
```

Comment: You need to use `strcmp` (or `strncmp`) to compare strings. `==` compares pointer values.

Comment: Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Note that the CRLF characters would come before the null byte, not after it.  You would also run into problems with long lines — longer than 254 characters.  There are ways to write the code so that is simply not an issue. On your current scheme, you need to search for … well, maybe use `strlen()`, or maybe use `strchr()`, or `strcspn()`, or … there are many ways to do it, but the shown code isn't one of them.

Comment: It's not about comparing strings, its about opening a file in text mode; It is not a duplicate of the question/answer marked.

Comment: In addition to all the bugs other people have pointed out, you may need to open both files in binary mode (`"rb"`, `"wb"`) to even see CRLFs in the first place, and to prevent the C library from converting `\n` back to `\r\n` on output; you aren't checking for any errors; your logic for _replacing_ `\r\n` with `\n` is incorrect; and you don't handle long lines correctly;

Comment: If you are converting line feeds, there is no good reason to use `fgets`.  That function is line oriented, and if you're worried about the line endings, then pretty much by definition you don't trust your input.  And `fgets` is overkill.  Read the the file one character at a time with `fgetc` or `getc`.  You only need to keep track of a small amount of state.  (There are 2 states: one in which the previous character read was `\r`, one in which it wasn't)

Comment: Thanks to everyone, who reply to my question. I am really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a whole bunch of bugs:

- You may need to open `in.txt` in `"rb"` mode, instead of `"r"` mode, to see the CRLF line endings in the first place.
- You may need to open `out.txt` in `"wb"` mode, instead of `"w"` mode, to prevent the C library from undoing your work.
- You cannot compare string literals with `==`.  You *can* compare one character of a string to a *character* literal with `==`, but that's not what you're doing, and it only works for single characters; a CRLF sequence is *two* characters.
- You cannot *replace* a two-character sequence with a one-character sequence within a mutable C string by simple assignment.  You would need to use `memmove` to shift all the characters after the replacement down one.
- You do not properly handle very long lines.
- You do not check whether `fopen` succeeded, or for any other I/O errors.
- [`while (!feof (fp))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

A better way to write this program is with a main loop that goes *character by character*, something like

```
  int c;
  while ((c = getc(ifp)) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\r') {
      putc('\n', ofp);
      c = getc(ifp);
      if (c == EOF) break;
      if (c == '\n') continue;
    }
    putc(c, ofp);
  }
```

This converts both `\r\n` and bare `\r` to `\n`, because bare `\r` is very rare nowadays, but *was* used as the line terminator on some historical OSes (notably classic MacOS), and there isn't anything else sensible to do with it.

It's important that `c` be an `int`, not a `char`, so that it can hold EOF as well as all possible characters.

Comment: Note; Re: "You do not check for I/O errors." This code does check for input errors.  It does not check for output errors (which are quite rare).

Comment: @chux Not in my experience -- but mostly what I meant was they're not checking the result of `fopen`.